# Difference between alert var++ and var+1

Tags: javascript

I'm a little bit confuse about this process:

```
function counter() {
    var count = 0;
    return function() {
        alert(count++);
    }
}
var count = counter();
count();
```

Why after execute the code, the alert was still 0 but if I change "count++" to "count+1", the alert output was 1.
Could anyone explain to me the process.

Comment: change it to ++count, and watch what happens...

Comment: `alert(count++)` will first alert the value of `count` and then increment it by one. This is called post-Increment operator. You can use `++count` to first increment the value and then alert.

Comment: Did you [read any documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_())?

Comment: @Tushar thanks bro, forget that simple things haha

Comment: @Felix Kling thanks bro... forget that stuffs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) count++ tells the script to alert(count) and then increase by one.

2) ++count tels the script to increase count by one and then alert.

3) count+1 is evaluated for the alert, but it does not change the variable value of count.

Comment: 1) is not quite right. `count` is increased before the alert happens, but `count++` doesn't return the updated value of `count`, it returns the previous value of `count`.

Comment: "count+1 is evaluated for the alert, but it does not change the variable value of count."---for my understand,after the alert invoke the  count variable will remain 0 or if this happen in a loop for 10 times the count variable will remain 0--is that you mean?

Comment: @Mohammad count does not change